# Convert HTMl table to JSON + http://convertjson.com/html-table-to-json.htm

Tags: php, html, json, ruby

I am looking for some solution to convert my HTML table data to json. This website is doing similar

http://convertjson.com/html-table-to-json.htm

I am looking for help code to convert. I tried some solutions but at some point of end there's issue.

All i need is a json output so i can convert it in array and proceed further.

Comment: could you perhaps include your html table

Comment: Here's the sample table : http://aryan786.srkm.in/table.html

If you convert this table html on given site link. It works just fine but with own code some error.

Would like to understand what they may be using in order to fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to do that.

Sample table:

```
<table id='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='table_head' width='80px'>Header1</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='435px'>Header2</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='100px'>Header3</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='100px'>Header4</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='100px'>Header5</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='100px'>Header6</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='100px'>Header7</th>
            <th class='table_head' width='80px'>Header8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Rows -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For selecting data from table you can use this code

```
   $('#table tr').each(function (index, tr) {
        var cols = [];

        //get td of each row and insert it into cols array
        $(this).find('td').each(function (colIndex, c) {
            cols.push(c.textContent);
        });

        //insert this cols(full rows data) array into tableData array
        tableData.push(cols);
      });
```

And to encode your data as json you can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify);

```
JSON.stringify(tableData)
```